# gitlab-ci register runner x509

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-omnibus

I'am trying to register my runner but I cannot understand exactly how to do. I have already read all post about this issue but I cannot find my response.

**On gitlab master**
**gitlab.rb**

```
letsencrypt['enable'] = true
```

I have uncommented ligne in gitlab.rb to use let's encrypt cert generated by gitlab when I do `gitlab-ctl reconfigure`.
EDIT:
Using reconfigure I have this error but https is working fine.

There was an error running gitlab-ctl reconfigure:

```
letsencrypt_certificate[gitlab-ci] (letsencrypt::http_authorization line 5) had an error: Acme::Client::Error::RejectedIdentifier: acme_certificate[staging] (/opt/gitlab/embedded/cookbooks/cache/cookbooks/letsencrypt/resources/certificate.rb line 25) had an error: Acme::Client::Error::RejectedIdentifier: Error creating new order :: Cannot issue for "gitlab-ci": Domain name needs at least one dot
```

In `/etc/gitlab/ssl/` I have 3 news file.

```
192.168.1.60.crt
192.168.1.60.key
192.168.1.60.key-staging
```

To register runner must I copy content of .crt in a file and specify the path with argument `tls-ca-file` ?

**On runner**

```
gitlab-runner register tls-ca-file /etc/gitlab-runner/ssl/192.168.1.60.crt


ERROR: Registering runner... failed                 runner=cMCbAs1i status=couldn't execute POST against https://192.168.1.60/api/v4/runners: Post https://192.168.1.60/api/v4/runners: x509: cannot validate certificate for 192.168.1.60 because it doesn't contain any IP SANs
PANIC: Failed to register the runner. You may be having network problems.
```

Someone please can help?

Thx

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution.

**Important**: **Certificat created with let's encrypt by gitlab reconfigure, the issuer is gitlab, so it's not recognized like CA authority**

Solution is working with certs created by gitlab or your own certs.

I have used certificat from my compagny.

Copy certificat in the master into the runner.
I created folder `certs` in `/etc/gitlab-runner/` and copied it into

```
mymastergit.mycompagny.com or mycompagny.com
```

When doing the register the certificat must have the exact name of the master fqdn.
ex:

```
gitlab-runner register tls-ca-file=/etc/ssl/certs/mymastergit.mycompagny.com.crt
```